# How to add a recyclerView to the bottom of my layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to add RecyclerView at the bottom to my layout, but it is in wrong position.

Now I Have:

[image]

Now RecyclerView is too far down and cuts half of RecyclerView. I Only want RecyclerView at the bottom of my layout but I can't do it.

This is my layout code:

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="showresultactivity.SlideTabsActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/mapView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/mapView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/mapView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mapView" />



        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" /><!--this line make too far down, without it my recyclerview will be at the top of my layout-->
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My RecyclerView layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

tools:context="showresultactivity.SlideTabsActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewInfoWindowMarker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

My recyclerView row item xml :

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FCFCFC"
    tools:context="showresultactivity.SlideTabsActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        app:cardElevation="1dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagesSrcUrl"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/first"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/description"
                android:text="some text"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/third"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:text="some text"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                />
            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagesSrcUrl"
                android:layout_below="@id/first"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:text="some text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                />




        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



</LinearLayout>
<ImageButton
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/cardViewNext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_next_black" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/cardVievPrevious"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_previous_black" />
```

**EDIT**
I forgot that I have also bottom navigation and the recycler should be at the bottom map but above the bottom navigation.
Layout with bottom nav:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="SlideTabsActivity"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/app_name">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_3" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />



    <include layout="@layout/bottom_navigation_view" android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

bottom_navigation_view:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/bottomRelativeLayout">
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_bottom"

        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your question is a little bit incoherent. What do you want to do? I'm guessing that the position of your recycler view is okay but you want to adjust the height in such a way that the contents of the recycler view are never cut off. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not really used to constraint layouts (I dread them) but I have a tiny suggestion.. You can use this to align your recyclerview to the bottom of the of the parent view: `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`

Comment: Maybe add a margin to the bottom?

Comment: @Taslim yes that is what I want

Comment: Consider using the method I prescribed earlier. Your code just requires a little tweaking, that's all. Although one thing you SHOULD'NT do is using arbitrary values to represent the height of your recyclerview; while it may appear correctly on your device, it might not show properly on other devices with different screen sizes. I'll write a detailed answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line to your framelayout would help you achieve that positioning:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

**Also remember to set the height of your frame layout to:** `wrap content`. The purpose of the line above is to fix/pin your frame layout to the bottom of your constraint layout; any eventual expansion would be upward. Therefore, the contents of your frame layout will never overlap. If there is need for extra space, your frame layout will project upwards while still being fixed to the bottom of the constraint layout.

You can check this for reference on more XML attributes on Constraint layouts: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html

PS:

*You can remove the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` part of your frame layout; it's not necessary anymore*

Comment: I forgot that i have also bottom navigation and now it is at the bottom of my map but now is where is bottom navigation, I edit my post and add this layout where i have bottom navigation